# Flexbox image scale-to-fit using "overflow: auto" doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's consider the following code:

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XOMwctj.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

It works in Chrome, the image is scaled to fit the available height and gets centered:
[image: chrome behaviour]

But it doesn't behave the same way in Firefox:
[image: firefox behaviour]

It seems like the image gets scaled correctly, but Firefox doesn't change the container width to accommodate the smaller image. Is this a bug? Is there any way around that?

Comment: You’ve centered container but you haven’t centered the img within it.

Comment: Looks like the problem is Firefox and Chrome handles container `div`s' widths differently. In Chrome, it expands as much as needed while in Firefox, it expands more. Not sure what's the root cause of this but as @AHaworth said, just center `img` inside your container `div` and you should get the same result.

Comment: @technophyle But is there a way to center the `img` inside the container without `position: absolute;` on the image? Doing so with or without `position: relative;` on the container, seems to breake the layout if there is more than one container `div` inside the center `div`, as the container no longer occupies any space inside the flexbox, which is the case in my real application.

Comment: Of course you can. Just add `text-align: center` to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is maintaining the original width of the .center element when it contains a child that doesn't fit its width (in this case, the .container element). This is why you're seeing the horizontal scrollbar in Firefox.

The .wrapper element is used to center the .container element, and the .wrapper is set to have max-width: 100%; to ensure it doesn't exceed the available width. This should help maintain the centered layout and adjust the container's width to the smaller image size in both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%; /* Ensure the wrapper doesn't exceed 100% width */
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XOMwctj.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it's still the same in firefox.

Comment: Lets try a different approach then. See my edited code.